# How minimum runway length is calculated for PAC P-750 XSTOL?

Tags: safety, runways, skydiving

I'm not a pilot, but have interest in the question from a safety perspective, as a skydiver and drop zone operator.

I read the [POH](https://www.redskyventures.org/doc/other-poh/PacificAerospace-PAC750XL-POH.pdf) of [PAC P-750 XSTOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAC_P-750_XSTOL), and tried reading a bit about the calculations, but could not make it out.

Given the parameters below, how is the minimum runway length is calculated for PAC P-750 XSTOL?

Parameters:

- Pac 750 XSTOL
- 15 knots cross wind 90
- 0° flaps
- 6500 LBS TOW
- Runway is 1500 feet above MSL
- ISA +10°

Comment: I don't think you can.  The manual only lists takeoff performance data for 20° flaps and doesn't specify a correction factor for 0° flaps.  FWIW, even if the 0° data was there, you wouldn't need all of the parameters you specify.  A direct crosswind doesn't matter, since the headwind/tailwind component is zero.  ISA correction is calculated based on pressure altitude and air temperature and you only specify true altitude and no temperature, but since you already gave us an ISA correction we don't need them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not on the basis of the POH you linked. Taking off with 0° flaps for that aircraft is outside the POH limitations chapter.

2.20 Flap Limitations:

> Approved flap ranges.
>
> TAKEOFF FLAP: 20°
>
> LANDING FLAP: 40°

4.27 Amplified Procedures - Normal Takeoff):

> A wing flap setting of 20°  is recommended for all takeoffs. 20° flap
> will provide the best takeoff performance. The Normal Takeoff
> technique is to be used for Short Field operations and is the
> technique used to derive the performance data in Section 5.